# substring operation on blob text in informix

Tags: informix

How can I substring a text of BLOB datatype in informix? If the operation is possible only on text of char datatype, is it possible to convert from BLOB to char (like to_char in oracle)?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: While in Informix there is plenty of large binary types you can add your table definition (`CREATE TABLE`) and describe what values are stored in blob field (is it long text as binary data as some music, photos etc). Give us also information about your server version and client environment (is it ODBC, JDBC, what version of Client SDK).

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring operator: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls1069.htm

Code looks like:

```
select txt, txt[3,5] from  _text_test
```

(txt is of `BLOB` type, but I also tested using `TEXT` type).

**WARNING!** In my tests such select gives different 2nd field values when executed by JDBC (correct values) and ODBC (seems incorrect). My ODBC Client is 3.70TC1, and JDBC.3.70.JC1DE. Please check if it works correctly in your environment. For txt value=`1234567890` I got `123` using ODBC and `345` using JDBC. Seems like bug!

Comment: can we also have trim, length function on blob type?

Comment: `LENGTH()` only. `TRIM()` gives error: `Trim character and trim source must be of string data type`