# operations on blob data in informix

Tags: blob, informix, substring, trim

How can we use substring, trim, length operations on some text of blob datatype. And how can we update a column of blob datatype using query?

Thanks,

Comment: The same comment as for your last query: show us what kind of blob you are using, with which version of Informix server and Informix client.

Answer (score 4):

With difficulty!

First of all, which of the 4 various types of blob are you discussing:

- BYTE
- TEXT
- BLOB
- CLOB

These come in pairs (like Sith Lords): there is a binary version (BYTE, BLOB) and a text version (TEXT, CLOB).  There's also another pairing: old (BYTE, TEXT) and newer (BLOB, CLOB).  The BYTE and TEXT types were introduced with Informix OnLine 4.00 in about 1989.  The BLOB and CLOB types were introduced with Informix Universal Server 9.00 in 1996, and are also known as SmartBlobs.

However, there's a very real sense in which it doesn't matter which of the types you are referring to.

There are very few operations that can be performed on BYTE and TEXT blobs.  They can be fetched and stored, but for all practical purposes, that's all.  I believe you can use LENGTH to determine the length of a TEXT blob.  I don't believe there are any methods available to update part of BYTE or TEXT blob; it is an all-or-nothing replacement.  Further, the replacement is from a host variable of the appropriate type - there are no BYTE or TEXT literals.

The situation is a bit better with SmartBlobs, but I'm not an expert on them.  There are mechanisms for obtaining a LO (large object) handle and then manipulating that, but I don't think those are available server-side (from SQL or SPL).  I may be willfully not understanding what's available with the SmartBlobs, but I think the operations are only available from programming APIs and not within SQL.  There are no BLOB or CLOB literals either.  However, you can use SQL to load from files (FILETOBLOB, FILETOCLOB) and write to files (LOTOFILE) - with the files either on the server or on the client.

Answer (score 1):

I have already answered your question about substring: [substring operation on blob text in informix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460623/substring-operation-on-blob-text-in-informix)
. With BLOBs you can use substring operator, but not `SUBSTRING()` nor `SUBST()` functions.

You can also use `LENGTH()`, but not `TRIM()`.

Example code:

```
CREATE TABLE _text_test (id serial, txt_vch varchar(200),  txt_text text);
INSERT INTO _text_test (txt_vch, txt_text) VALUES ('1234567890', '1234567890');
SELECT txt_vch, txt_text, txt_vch[3,5], txt_text[3,5], length(txt_text) FROM _text_test;
```

In my example I used `TEXT` blob type (Jonathan showed you more blob types, you should show us what kind of blob you use in question). Last select shows usage of substring operator and `LENGTH()` function. You can replace `LENGTH()` function with other functions like `TRIM()` to test it with your environment. In my case `TRIM()` test ends with:

```
ODBC Error: -880 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]
Trim character and trim source must be of string data type.
```

Last select works well with JDBC 3.70JC1 driver, but it seems that ODBC 3.70TC1 driver has bug and shows 3 first chars: `123` instead of `345`. Test it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In recent version (12.10) there is [DBMS_LOB package](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.dbext.doc/ids_r0055115.htm?lang=en)
However it doesn't work as documented: for example there is no dbms_lob.get_length function. Instead I've found that dbms_lob_get_length is working as expected.
So for CLOB fields you have following usefull operations:

- dbms_lob_get_length;
- dbms_lob_instr;
- dbms_lob_substr (unfortunately it gets data after get_length too);

I've found also one undocumented but very, very useful function: dbms_lob_new_clob which gets lvarchar argument and it converts it to CLOB.
I know that this answer is very late. I think that it can be usefull for other people searching ways to handle blobs in Informix (I've found this post few days ago when I was starting mini-research about using blobs for storing xml).